# On change of language in Kendo grid I am not getting data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently, I am working on Kendo-grid, with Thymleaf. I am facing an issue, I'm trying to use multiple languages in the kendo grid table. Whenever I try to apply different language on the grid, `<thead>` header tag is coming up with applied language but it seems that data not displayed in grid `<tbody>`. Grid table shows data properly when I apply the English language.

```html
<table>
<thead >            
<tr>            
<th><span th:text="#{user_name}" th:remove="tag"></span></th> 
<th><span th:text="#{first_name}" th:remove="tag"></span></th>          </tr>          
</thead>         
<tbody>              
<tr th:each="user : ${users}"            th:object="${user}"               th:classappend="${isDeleted} ? item-deleted : ''">                <td th:text="${user.username}"></td> 
<td th:text="${user.firstname}"></td>                                         </tr>          
</tbody>         
</table>
```

Comment: i have also created one demo on kendo's site please check below link..help me to fix this issue asap.
https://dojo.telerik.com/uGoViYIH/2

Comment: After adding `dataSource: {data: {}}` at the end of the demo's `kendoGrid` script, the rows became visible.

Comment: Thanks for Replay It's shows the data on grid but also shows Loader on the screen.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't figure out a way to remove the loader :) I'll let you know if I can make it work.

Comment: Adding `setTimeout(function(e) {$(".k-loading-image").hide();});` just above the `</script>` closing tag made the loader animation go. I hope it helps.

Comment: ya it's work but i not able to insert and edit the data